# Is there an observer/plugin to Modify shipping cost after tax is applied to it?

Tags: magento2

Trying to work around an issue where Shipping cost is set fixed to 8.695. Excluding Tax but we want a tax of 15% added. (Other shipping methods calculate costs Excluding Tax)

When tax is applied this should be exactly $10.00.
However, I am getting $10.01 as internally Magento / Shipping method costs are being rounded to the Configured Currency, before and during checkout costing calculations.

Awkward right.

Or is there a way I can set one shipping method to say its cost is already Inclusive of GST?
Does not appear to be.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159276/71445 this helps you?

Comment: I'll give it a look thanks @Rustyjim